# How to display npm-debug.log in app engine standard enviroment

Tags: google-app-engine

I found error messages in gcp stackdriver loggings as followings:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T22_18_01_715Z-debug.log
```

Is there a way to check this `npm-debug.log` which is located in app engine standard environment?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have access to your instances in app engine standard. However, you can [access them with App Engine flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance)